# Winforms gridControl Cell DevExpress 13.1.5.0 Coded UI Tests: Cannot locate the cell in playback

Tags: visual-studio-2012, devexpress, coded-ui-tests

In *Visual Studio 2012* and I have a *Winforms application* using *DevExpress 13.1.5.0* controls. I am trying to automate Coded UI tests using the *DevExpress 13.1.5.0 Coded UI Extension*.

I am facing a problem in a *gridControl* where I have to delete a record. In the playback, it doesn't find the right cell.

When looking at the cell Search Properties, I find the Name as being like `gridControlGridControlCell[View][Row]9[Column]...`, it is therefore relative to the number of rows in the grid.
I have tried to add Search Properties like *FriendlyName, ControlType* and removing this one without success.

Is there a way to have a cell located in a gridControl without relative positionning in the grid itself?. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You have a Universal-Licence and devexpress-controls can be tested?

Comment: Yes I have Universal license and they can be tested

Comment: So I would recommend you to open a support case on devexpress homepage. You pay a lot of many and they may can help you more exact. If you do, please post the link.